# Issue with returning a string

Tags: javascript, string, setinterval

I have written this code to get the value of the Timer in a div :

```js
var timerGenerator = (function() {
        var time = {
            centiSec: 0,
            secondes: 0,
            minutes: 0,
            hours: 0
        };
        var container = document.createElement("div");
        var timeDisplay = function() {
            function smoothDisplay(value) {
                return (value < 10 ? '0' : '') + value;
            }
            return "" + smoothDisplay(this.hours) + ":" + smoothDisplay(this.minutes) + ":" + smoothDisplay(this.secondes) + "." + smoothDisplay(this.centiSec);
        };
        var boundTimeDisplay = timeDisplay.bind(time);

        var timeUpdate = function() {
            container.innerHTML = boundTimeDisplay();
            //console.log(container);
            this.centiSec++;
            if(this.centiSec === 100) {
                this.centiSec = 0;
                this.secondes++;
            }
            if(this.secondes === 60) {
                this.secondes = 0;
                this.minutes++;
            }
            if(this.minutes === 60) {
                this.minutes = 0;
                this.hours++;
            }
        };
        var boundTimeUpdate = timeUpdate.bind(time);

        window.setInterval(boundTimeUpdate,10);
        console.log(container);
        return container; 
    })();
```

This code works when I link the var timerGenartor with a div. But, now I would like to return the var container into a string. So I changed my code to this : (I just changed the initialization of container and this value)

```js
    var timerGenerator = (function() {
        var time = {
            centiSec: 0,
            secondes: 0,
            minutes: 0,
            hours: 0
        };
        var container = "";

        var timeDisplay = function() {
            function smoothDisplay(value) {
                return (value < 10 ? '0' : '') + value;
            }
            return "" + smoothDisplay(this.hours) + ":" + smoothDisplay(this.minutes) + ":" + smoothDisplay(this.secondes) + "." + smoothDisplay(this.centiSec);
        };
        var boundTimeDisplay = timeDisplay.bind(time);

        var timeUpdate = function() {
            container = boundTimeDisplay();
            //console.log(container);
            this.centiSec++;
            if(this.centiSec === 100) {
                this.centiSec = 0;
                this.secondes++;
            }
            if(this.secondes === 60) {
                this.secondes = 0;
                this.minutes++;
            }
            if(this.minutes === 60) {
                this.minutes = 0;
                this.hours++;
            }
        };
        var boundTimeUpdate = timeUpdate.bind(time);

        window.setInterval(boundTimeUpdate,10);
        console.log(container);
        return container;
    })();
```

With this modification nothing is returned or display in the console and I don't understand why. However, the comment "console.log" gives me good the timer. So, why the first console.log displays the good result and not the second one ?

Comment: Th first one returns empty `div` and the second one returns empty string, since you write in the console before the `setInterval` fires. Let me know what's your actual purpose instead of `console.log` and I will change the code accordingly

Comment: The first one doesn't return an empty div because when i make a div in another js file and gives it the value of timerGenerator that works. My actual purpose is to return the string into a span tag but the span tag came from another js file.

Comment: I meant the `console.log` for the div which is empty `div`. Okay I will change your code.

Comment: I have updated the code below, please have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The working code as you expected with two JS functions

```js
// JS 1
var timerGenerator = (function() {
        var time = {
            centiSec: 0,
            secondes: 0,
            minutes: 0,
            hours: 0
        };
        var container = "";

        var timeDisplay = function() {
            function smoothDisplay(value) {
                return (value < 10 ? '0' : '') + value;
            }
            return "" + smoothDisplay(this.hours) + ":" + smoothDisplay(this.minutes) + ":" + smoothDisplay(this.secondes) + "." + smoothDisplay(this.centiSec);
        };
        var boundTimeDisplay = timeDisplay.bind(time);

        var timeUpdate = function() {
            container = boundTimeDisplay();
            //console.log(container);
            this.centiSec++;
            if(this.centiSec === 100) {
                this.centiSec = 0;
                this.secondes++;
            }
            if(this.secondes === 60) {
                this.secondes = 0;
                this.minutes++;
            }
            if(this.minutes === 60) {
                this.minutes = 0;
                this.hours++;
            }
          return container;
        };
        var boundTimeUpdate = timeUpdate.bind(time);

        return boundTimeUpdate;
    })();


// JS 2
var spanGenerator = (function() {
  var container = document.createElement('span');
  
  window.setInterval(function(){
    container.innerHTML = timerGenerator();
  }, 10);
  
  return container;
  
})();

document.getElementById('timer').appendChild(spanGenerator);
```

```html
<div id="timer"></div>
```

Comment: Why did I not think earlier to put the setInterval into the the second JS. It works perfectly, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

It can be because your container is empty as it is initialized in timeUpdate function which is eventually called 10ms later(for the first time) because of the setInterval. U will have to call the timeUpdate function before putting it in setInterval.